# angularjs module: extending dependencies?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, module

### Current Situation

I am trying to understand how to build an adaptive website with angular.  Using a directory structure on the server (for scripts) along the lines of:

```
/scripts
  /external
  /phone
  /tablet
  /desktop
  ...
```

together with libraries like `modernizr` and `LABjs`, I can set up something like:

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<head> ... </head>

<body ng-controller="GlobalCtrl">
  <div ng-view=""></div>

<script src="/scripts/external/LABjs"></script>
<script>
  var prefix = '';
  switch(deviceType) {
    case 'phone': prefix = '/scripts/phone'; break;
    case 'tablet': prefix = '/scripts/tablet'; break;
    case 'desktop': prefix = '/scripts/desktop'; break;
  }

$LAB
// load third party scripts
.script("/scripts/external/modernizer.js")
.script("/scripts/external/angular.js")
.script(etc...).wait()

// load device specific scripts, last should bootstrap module 'app'
.script(prefix.concat('/app.js'))
.script(etc...)
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Then, of course, the directories `/scripts/{phone,tablet,desktop}`, etc.. would contain a file:

**app.js**

```
angular.module('app',['device', 'specific', 'dependencies'])

// all other controllers inherit from this controller's scope
.controller('GlobalCtrl', ['device', 'specific', 'injectables',
    function(device, specific, injectables) {
        // setup global helpers here, e.g. user authentication
}]);
```

This setup ensures that no unnecessary modules/scripts are loaded for each type of device, e.g. the `/scripts/{phone,tablet}` directory may contain `Hammer.js` whereas `/scripts/desktop` would not.

However, the problem with this is that there could be a good amount of overlap in the definition of `GlobalCtrl` in each of the the `/scripts/{phone,tablet,desktop}/app.js` files.

---

## Possibilities?

To remedy the situation, it would be nice to have something like:

**/scripts/app.js**

```
angular.module('app', ['modules', 'common', 'to', 'all'])

.controller('GlobalCtrl', ['injectables', 'common', 'to', 'all',
    function(injectables, common, to, all) {
        // code common to all
}]);
```

then the `/scripts/{phone,tablet,desktop}/app.js` files would have:

**e.g., /scripts/phone/app.js**

```
// add phone specific, module dependencies to angular.module('app')
// add code to 'GlobalCtrl' specific to phones
```

- Question 1) Is the above possible so that code does not need to be repeated in each `GlobalCtrl` while not loading unnecessary dependencies?
- Question 2) On the other hand, if I did:

**/scripts/app.js**

```
angular.module('app', ['common_dependencies', 'app.phone', 'app.tablet', 'app.desktop']);
```

where in each `/scripts/{phone,tablet,desktop}/app.js` I had:

**e.g., /scripts/phone/app.js**

```
angular.module('app.phone', ['phone', 'specific', 'dependencies']);
```

then `angular.module('app')` would load *ALL* device specific dependencies for *EVERY* type of device, right?  For instance, if `app.phone` and `app.tablet` had `angular-gestures` as a dependency, then that module would be loaded by `app` every time (even when it is not used by the `app.desktop` module)?

---

Perhaps I am going about this the wrong way.  If you have insight as to the best practice for initializing modules and loading scripts, please inform me!  I'm not sure if the code in `GlobalCtrl` common to each type of device can be injected to each controller?

---

## First Solution?

While writing this, I realized that I am (probably) thinking about it backwards.  I think what I should do is have:

**/scripts/app.js**

```
angular.module('app', ['common', 'dependencies'])

.controller('GlobalCtrl', ['common', 'injectables',
    function(common, injectables) {
        // common code here
}]);
```

and then inject this module into each device specific module in the directories `/scripts/{phone,tablet,desktop}/app.js` like:

**e.g., /scripts/phone/app.js**

```
angular.module('app.phone', ['app', 'phone_specific_dependencies'])

// extend 'GlobalCtrl' here somehow
```

Finally, I would need to use modernizr to (conditionally) bootstrap one of `app.phone`, `app.tablet`, `app.desktop` in the script loader.

## Second Solution?

Thought of another one.  For each device type, make a child controller to `GlobalCtrl`.

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<head> ... </head>

<body ng-controller="GlobalCtrl">
  <div ng-controller="Global.{{DEVICE}}Ctrl">
    <div ng-view=""></div>
  </div>

<script src="/scripts/external/LABjs"></script>
<script>
    // script load etc...
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**/scripts/app.js**

```
angular.module('app', ['common', 'dependencies'])

.constant('DEVICE', 'Phone') // set dynamically using modernizr

.controller('GlobalCtrl', ['common', 'injectables',
    function(common, injectables) {
        // common code
}]);
```

**e.g., /scripts/phone/app.js**

```
angular.module('app.phone', ['app','phone_specific_dependencies'])

.controller('Global.PhoneCtrl', ['phone_injectables',
    function(phone_injectables) {
        // scope here inherits from GlobalCtrl
}]);
```

Comment: You seem to have everything sorted out, so what's the question ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone stops by, solution 2 seems to be the best.